# Are increases to log retention retroactive?

Tags: google-cloud-logging

re: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/storage#logs-retention

If I have a 30 day retention policy, then increase that policy to 90 days, do logs that are 30 days old stick around for another 60 days?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log retention changes *are* retroactive.

Just finished testing this out by adding a log message to a logs bucket with single-day retention, verifying that it was deleted after a day. Added a new log message, then increased retention to a week -- two days later and the log remains.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, so my initial answer was correct and as [document-1](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/bucket-lock#overview) says " A retention policy retroactively applies to existing objects in the bucket as well as new objects added to the bucket"

Answer (score 0):

A retention policy retroactively applies to existing objects in the bucket as well as new objects added to the bucket.Please see the document [1](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/bucket-lock#overview) for more details.

You can list [2](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/logging/buckets/list) your logging buckets and look for the retention period for the _Default bucket:

$ gcloud beta logging buckets list

You can also set it to a different amount of retention days [3](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/storage#custom-retention) with:

$ gcloud beta logging buckets update _Default --location=global --retention-days=[RETENTION_DAYS]

Comment: I don't think Cloud Storage buckets are the same thing as Cloud Logging buckets. I don't see any of my logs buckets within the Cloud Storage bucket browser.

Comment: I'm just going to create a logs bucket w/ retention of 1 day, verify a log is removed after a day, then add another, increase the retention policy, and verify it remains. Will update here sometime next week.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I will wait for your test results.